# Help understanding salary terms (USD to INR)

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job

I am from India and I recently got a job offer with the following terms:

1. Monthly gross salary of USD 4000
2. To be paid in the Indian Rupee equivalent at the Company’s main bankers Indian Rupee /United States Dollar buy rate on the date on which the payment is made
3. Salary will be payable monthly in arrears

Would my gross salary be 4000*75 (buy rate)= ~Rs. 302059 or would it be based on PPP, which is around Rs.50,000.

Of course I have asked my company to clarify but it is Christmas break and they will take time to get back to me

Comment: What is PPP? Anyways, best is to wait for the company to get back.

Comment: We don't know, we can't tell. Wait to get the official response from the company.

Comment: Purchasing power parity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every month the company will take $4000, convert it to Indian Rupees at the bank used by the company (using their buy rate for that day) and transfer the result to your account. Purchasing Power Parity is not in any way involved. This is an absolutely normal way for a company to pay a salary to a worker in a country they don't have a big presence in.

Be aware that this means your salary in INR will vary each month depending on the exchange rate, potentially by quite a lot.

Clarifying with the company is a good idea, but I'm fairly sure this is what they mean.

Comment: Are the _normal deductions_  composed of a handling fee and an additional forex-fee for the exchange?

Comment: Additionally: _"Be aware that this means your salary in INR will vary each month depending on the exchange rate, potentially by quite a lot."_ - Taking the sort of stable dollar and the more volatile INR into account, that can be interpreted as beneficial to the OP because inflation is buffered by the exchange-rate, what do you think?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I meant the things that are normally deducted from salary in India, like tax. Only the company would know if a Forex fee was deducted. I would presume not, or they would say so.